# IIS Startup Behaviour flakey (Web API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

We have built our n-tier application using IIS to present a RESTful service using the Web API.

Unfortunately when we launch our application view, or run the web site from the URL, sometimes it works, other times it fails, with an ArugmentException stating that one of the fields is null.  We put the argument exception then as guarding - but clearly the type field is coming up as null when it shouldn't.

Since we used the basic Web API template, we have the following line in Global.asax.cs:

`RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

which in turn calls:

```
public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

}`

Now the thing to stress here is that this [almost] always works within visual studio/IIS Express.  However, when we come to deploy it to IIS proper, or indeed IIS Express outside of a visual studio context, it becomes flakey and doesn't work - however if you keep kicking it eventually it comes to life.

So far we have tried:

- Removing any references to ASP.NET 2.x that we can find (everything is built on .NET 4.5)
- Adding the following to Web.Config:
  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Any further ideas would be welcome - if you need any additional code, let me know and I'll add it (not knowing exactly what might be needed).

Thanks

Comment: is your app pool set for .net 4.0?

Comment: Is there something that gets logged to the event-viewer?

Comment: Make sure impersonation is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try debugging the web app while it is running under IIS, this will ignore any diffrences between IIS Express and IIS (proper).

You can attach to the `w3wp.exe` process while it is running (Visual Studio, Debug -> Attach)

When debugging startup code, you may need to include a call to `Debugger.Break()` as a temporary helper to allow Visual Studio to attach to the process.

Comment: Thanks - it did indeed turn out to be a related customisation that required on IIS having loaded certain assemblies, but when run outside the development environment, IIS was too lethargic!